# Sums not working with adding and removing Dynamic Fields

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, dynamic-data

I have a script that calls to a Database to get Autocomplete data.

Once the specific Autocomplete data (Item Name) has been chosen a few other fields are populated, namely: Item Code, Price & Quantity.

When the quantity is changed the Lines Total field changes to "Quantity * Price" total.

There is the option to carry on adding rows Dynamically and autocomplete each in the same fashion ... there is a Grand Total that adds each line total together.

My issues are that the grand total only changes when the Quantity is changed, it should load on the focus of Price in each line - also, removing a line does not remove that spcific Line Totals ammount from the Grand Total and if you change the very first lines quantity (only the first line is affected) it re-sets the Grand total to anything that line has now added up to ... Please can someone look at my code.

The live version is at
http://cardoso.co.za/form/

You can also get the files there too if you browse to
http://cardoso.co.za/form/form.zip

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!!!

Edit here's some code from the entire script:

```
    var $itemsTable = $('#itemsTable');
var rowTemp = [
'<tr class="item-row">',
'<td><a id="deleteRow"><img src="images/icon-minus.png" alt="Remove Item" title="Remove Item"></a></td>',
'<td><input name="itemType" class="itemType" id="itemType" tabindex="1" style="width:350px;"/></td>',
'<td align="center"><input name="itemCode" class="itemCode" id="itemCode" readonly="readonly" style="width:60px;" tabindex="-1"/></td>',
'<td align="center"><input name="itemQty" class="itemQty" id="itemQty" tabindex="2" style="width:40px;" maxlength="4" value=""/></td>',
'<td width="14%" align="center"><input name="itemPrice" class="itemPrice" id="itemPrice" readonly tabindex="-1"/></td>',
'<td width="17%" align="right"><input name="itemTotal" class="itemTotal" id="itemTotal" readonly tabindex="-1"/></td>',
'</tr>'
].join('');
$('#addRow').bind('click',function(){
var $row = $(rowTemp);
var $itemType = $row.find('#itemType');
var $itemCode = $row.find('.itemCode');
var $itemPrice = $row.find('.itemPrice');
var $itemQty = $row.find('.itemQty');
var $itemTotal = $row.find('.itemTotal');
if ( $('#itemType:last').val() !== '' ) {
$row.find('#itemType').autocomplete({
source: 'item-data.php',
minLength: 1,
select: function(event, ui) {
$itemType.val(ui.item.itemType);
$itemCode.val(ui.item.itemCode);
$itemPrice.val(ui.item.itemPrice);
$itemTotal.focus().val(ui.item.itemPrice); 
$itemQty.focus().val(1);
$itemQty.keyup(function() {
var Quantity = $itemQty.val();
var Prices = $itemPrice.val();
var ItemsTotal = Quantity * Prices;
$itemTotal.val(ItemsTotal.toFixed(2));
var Tsum = 0;
$('.itemTotal').each(function() {
if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
Tsum += parseFloat(this.value);
$('#toTally').val(Tsum.toFixed(2))
}
}); 
});
return false;
}
}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
return $( "<li></li>" )
.data( "item.autocomplete", item )
.append( "<a>" + item.itemType + "</a>" )
.appendTo( ul );
};
$('.item-row:last', $itemsTable).after($row); 
$('#minusRow').show();
$('#resetTable').show();
$($itemType).focus();
}
return false;
});
```

I have implemented the Array, Will post this instead soon, once I get it to work with ID's and Classes without jamming.

Comment: Please post your code here, so future Stack Overflow users may reference the same question.  Your code will likely change on your server.

Comment: I'm not so good at jQuery, but I think your are wrong using one and the same ID for every input field with price. Furthermore, your jquery sums the val() of this ID, which gets only the first row. There should be something like an array I guess

Comment: Thenks Sable - I tried adding my code, but it was too long :( I will try concatenate it.

Comment: Thanks Royal Bg - I too am not great with Jquery and have no idea where to start puting together an array for the Pricing and Totals etc. thus my question

Comment: According to one of the answers here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420707/array-of-ids-how-to-select-with-javascript-jquery - your should name your id's with serial numbers i.e. id_1, id_2, then select them with `$("[id^='id_]")`.

Comment: I am jsut trying to implement it now, I will see if it helps - I have tried 2 or 3 methods of transposing a counter to each id/class, but it breaks my query.

Comment: You don't have to post all of your code; just the relevant sections.  As it is, I didn't look at your code in the zip file, because it is just bad news, opening unknown files from off the internet, viruses et al. :)  Take a look at some other questions here, and you will see the code snippets are short (10-12 lines on average).  I usually separate the PHP, CSS, jQuery and HTML in my questions.

Comment: I will format my code into sections as you suggest and upload it shortly.

Comment: You can answer your own question below and accept it. Please don't put your answer in the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by doing the following :

```
            ( function($) {
        var pounter = 1;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var qounter = 1;
            var trounter = 1;

                //Count each instance and add number to Name
                $row.find('._ext_price_total_html').each(function() {
                $(this).attr({
                'name': function(_, name) {
                    return name + pounter },
                    });
                pounter++;
                })
            $row.find('.quantitys').each(function() {
                $(this).attr({
                'name': function(_, name) {
                    return name + qounter },
                    });
                qounter++;
                })  
            $('#quantity', function(){
                var Tsum = 0;
                $('[id^="_ext_price_total_html"]').each(function() {
                    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                    Tsum += parseFloat(this.value);
                    }
                        $('.toTally').val(Tsum.toFixed(2))                                                          
                })
                })
                $('#quantity').change(function(){
                var Tsum = 0;
                $('[id^="_ext_price_total_html"]').each(function() {
                    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                    Tsum += parseFloat(this.value);
                    }
                        $('.toTally').val(Tsum.toFixed(2))                              
                    })
                })
                $('#quantity').keyup(function(){
                var Tsum = 0;
                $('[id^="_ext_price_total_html"]').each(function() {
                    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                    Tsum += parseFloat(this.value);
                    }
                        $('.toTally').val(Tsum.toFixed(2))
                })
                })
        //adjust/subtract from total when removeing row 

        $('#deleteRow').live('click',function(){
var delAsk = confirm('Remove this item?');
        if (delAsk)
        {
        $(this).parents('.jshop_prod_cart').remove();
            var Tsum = 0;
                $('[id^="_ext_price_total_html"]').each(function() {
                    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                    Tsum += parseFloat(this.value);
                    }
                        $('.toTally').val(Tsum.toFixed(2))

                })
        }
        else
        {
            ('cancel');
            }
                });
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking on the check mark. Please don't put "SOLVED" in the title.