# How to select multiple element with an array in one time with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select multiple ids in one time. Here is my code:

```
let arr = ['#asd', '#qwe', '#zxc'];
```

I want to select this 3 element with their ids.

How can I do that?

Comment: This should do it `$(arr.join())`.

Comment: Hmm, with comma, right?

Comment: Comma is the default for `join`.

Comment: Join with a comma, that should work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array of IDs - how to select with JavaScript / JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420707/array-of-ids-how-to-select-with-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Multiple ID selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079011/jquery-multiple-id-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

This is documentation: [click](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

This is example:

```js
$('#asd,#qwe,#zxc')
```